# Talk back accessibility not working properly on google ads

Tags: android, kotlin, google-ad-manager

My android app in kotlin is using google ads manager dependency for displaying ads and talk back is not working properly for all ads. Sometimes it reads some garbage value rather then the content that's being fed to it. In addition to this, click to landing page is also not working properly. Has anyone have faced the similar situation?
I am using
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0`